# Unpack IEEE 754 Floating Point Number

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, ieee-754, pymodbus

I am reading two 16 bit registers from a tcp client using the [pymodbus](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.2/library/index.html) module. The two registers make up a 32 bit [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) encoded floating point number. Currently I have the 32 bit binary value of the registers shown in the code below.

```
start_address = 0x1112
reg_count = 2
client = ModbusTcpClient(<IP_ADDRESS>)
response = client.read_input_registers(start_address,reg_count)
reg_1 = response.getRegister(0)<<(16 - (response.getRegister(0).bit_length())) #Get in 16 bit format
reg_2 = response.getRegister(1)<<(16 - (response.getRegister(1).bit_length())) #Get in 16 bit format 
volts = (reg_1 << 16) | reg_2 #Get the 32 bit format
```

The above works fine to get the encoded value the problem is decoding it. I was going to code something like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXF-wcoeT0o) but I came across the 'f' format in the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module for IEEE 754 encoding. I tried decode the 32 bit float stored in *volts* in the code above using the unpack method in the struct module but ran into the following errors.

```
val = struct.unpack('f',volts)
>>> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

Ok tried convert it to a 32 bit binary string.

```
temp = bin(volts)
val = struct.unpack('f',temp)
>>> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Tried to covert it to a bytes like object as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249879/python-struct-unpack-errors-with-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not) and format in different ways.

```
val = struct.unpack('f',bytes(volts))
>>> TypeError: string argument without an encoding

temp = "{0:b}".format(volts)
val = struct.unpack('f',temp)
>>> ValueError: Unknown format code 'b' for object of type 'str'

val = struct.unpack('f',volts.encode())
>>> struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

Where do I add this buffer and where in the documentation does it say I need this buffer with the unpack method? It does say in the documentation

> The string must contain exactly the amount of data required by the format (len(string) must equal calcsize(fmt)).

The calcsize(fmt) function returns a value in bytes but the len(string) returns a value of the length of the string, no?

Any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT**

There is a solution to decoding below however a better solution to obtaining the 32 bit register value from the two 16 bit register values is shown below compared to the original in the question.

```
start_address = 0x1112
reg_count = 2
client = ModbusTcpClient(<IP_ADDRESS>)
response = client.read_input_registers(start_address,reg_count)
reg_1 = response.getRegister(0)
reg_2 = response.getRegister(1)
# Shift reg 1 by 16 bits
reg_1s = reg_1 << 16
# OR with the reg_2
total = reg_1s | reg_2
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want nothing to do with `bin`. try using something like `volts.to_bytes(4,byteorder='big')`

Comment: I did try this and it did run without any errors however the value was not correct, I posted a solution that solved my problem below. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @WK123 You probably want `byteorder='little'`, then.

Comment: Yes this seems to work, I have two functions for sorting the two different ways I will share in another solution maybe it may help someone out there who isn't using modbus library. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem using the [BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters()](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/modbus_payload.html) from the [pymodbus](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) moudule instead of the struct module. Note that **this solution is specific to the modbus smart meter device I am using** as the byte order and word order of the registers could change in other devices. It may still work in other devices to decode registers but I would advise to read the documentation of the device first to be sure. I left in the comments in the code below but when I refer to page 24 this is just for my device.

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder

start_address = 0x1112
reg_count = 2
client = ModbusTcpClient(<IP_ADDRESS>)
response = client.read_input_registers(start_address,reg_count)
# The response will contain two registers making a 32 bit floating point number
# Use the BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters() function to decode
# The coding scheme for a 32 bit float is IEEE 754 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754
# The MS Bytes are stored in the first address and the LS bytes are stored in the second address,
# this corresponds to a big endian byte order (Second parameter in function)
# The documentation for the Modbus registers for the smart meter on page 24 says that
# the low word is the first priority, this correspond to a little endian word order (Third parameter in function)
decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(response.registers, Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Little)
final_val = (decoder.decode_32bit_float())
client.close()
```

**EDIT** 
Credit to [juanpa-arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) and [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) the problem can be solved using the struct module also with the `byteorder='little'`. The two functions in the code below can be used if the byteorder is `little` or if the byte order is `big` depending upon the implementation.

```
import struct
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

def big_endian(response):
    reg_1 = response.getRegister(0)
    reg_2 = response.getRegister(1)
    # Shift reg 1 by 16 bits
    reg_1s = reg_1 << 16
    # OR with the reg_2
    total = reg_1s | reg_2
    return total

def little_endian(response):
    reg_1 = response.getRegister(0)
    reg_2 = response.getRegister(1)
    # Shift reg 2 by 16 bits
    reg_2s = reg_2 << 16
    # OR with the reg_1
    total = reg_2s | reg_1
    return(total)

start_address = 0x1112
reg_count = 2
client = ModbusTcpClient(<IP_ADDRESS>)
response = client.read_input_registers(start_address,reg_count)

# Little 
little = little_endian(response)
lit_byte = little.to_bytes(4,byteorder='little')
print(struct.unpack('f',lit_byte))

# Big 
big = big_endian(response)
big_byte = big.to_bytes(4,byteorder='big')
print(struct.unpack('f',big_byte))
```